# How to present parsed data to an XML built UI?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

It's probably obvious but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to link the data that has already been parsed to an XML built UI? As in, I want to make a template for where the data should go on the UI and when the Activity is called, it will plug the data into the XML created UI.

Comment: I cannot understand the question. Can you please elaborate? "XMLBuilt UI", "template"?

Answer (score 3):

So for example in your xml defintion you have

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/hello" ... />
```

Then in your code you'd write:

```
TextView txtHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
```

and then you have an object that you can, for example call `.setText()` on